# How to speed up screen refresh on MacPro + Bootcamp?

Tags: hardware, bootcamp, windows, display, refresh

I'm a .Net developer running Windows 7 Ultimate (x64) on a 2010 MacPro (2.27Ghz/6GB RAM) using Bootcamp. Until about a month ago its been, imo, the ultimate dev workstation. However recently I've noticed that Visual Studio 2010 takes a very long time to redraw its windows. This is most noticeable when switching to it after its been in the foreground.

I don't get this problem with other Windows apps and am baffled because the machine has more than enough grunt to handle a few MDI'd windows yet grinds for up to five minutes sometimes when reactivating the VS environment - the screen update seems to slow everything down. My colleagues are using identical hardware and software but running Windows under Parallels on their Macs does not lead to this behaviour.

I'm getting desperate (and I've asked this same question at StackOverflow.com) - does anyone know why this might be happening and whether there's a fix ...?

Comment: You seem to have ruled out any hardware or driver issues by having colleagues on identical hardware. You could swap hard drives with one to reassure you it's your software and not your mac?

Comment: I'm not getting this issue with any other applications regardless of how heavyweight they are. I also code in Java and haven't got this problem with Eclipse + numerous addons so I've narrowed it down to Visual Studio.

Comment: I would agree with it being Visual Studio - just you might not get many studio tuning wizards here on the Apple centric site. In boot camp, you've got a high end PC with a tool that only runs on Windows - you might get better answers in one of the development / super user groups by asking that directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I [asked the same question at Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6911744/visual-studio-2010-very-slow-display-update-on-macpro-running-win7-bootcamp/6911823#6911823) and got an answer which appears to have fixed my issues. Hardware acceleration (paradoxically) is what was slowing down my VS.

HTH somebody.